# Creating a multiple choice quiz module

Tags: modules

I'm trying to set up a simple quiz module. I'm using a Matrix field called `quiz`, with a plain text `question` field and an `answers` table field. In the table field, there's two columns, plain text `answer` and checkbox `correct`. See image:

[image]

The idea being that there's only one correct answer.

**EDIT:**
Using James' amazing code as a base, I've tried to get that into PHP and it's coming along ok. Still working on it...

```
$userAnswers = Craft::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParam('answers');
$user = Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity();

$allQuestions = $quiz->quizMatrix->all();
$numberOfQuestions = count($allQuestions);

$correctAnswersByQuestion = [];

foreach ($allQuestions as $question) {
    $correctAnswer = array_map(function($answer) {
        return (bool)$answer['correct'];
    }, $question['answers']);
    $correctAnswersByQuestion[] = $correctAnswer;
}

$totalCorrect = 0;

foreach ($userAnswers as $key => $value) {
    $questionIndex = $key;
    $answerIndex = $value;
    $isCorrect = $correctAnswersByQuestion[$questionIndex][$answerIndex];
    echo "<p>Question " . ($questionIndex+1) . " was " . ($isCorrect ? 'correct' : 'incorrect') . "</p>";
    $totalCorrect += $isCorrect ? 1 : 0;
}

$score = ($totalCorrect / $numberOfQuestions) * 100;
$data = 'Your score is '.$score.'%';
$response = Craft::$app->getResponse();
$response->data = $data;
return $response;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered doing this in Twig instead? If your needs are complex, then a custom module in PHP might be best, but since you described it as a "simple" quiz, I'd probably go with Twig. Here's a fully functional example:

```twig
{% set allQuestions = entry.quiz.all() %}
<form method="post">
    {% for question in allQuestions %}
        <h3>{{ question.question }}</h3>
        {% for answer in question.answers %}
            <label for="answer-{{ question.id }}-{{ loop.index0 }}">
                <input type="radio" name="answers[{{ loop.parent.loop.index0 }}]" value="{{ loop.index0 }}" id="answer-{{ question.id }}-{{ loop.index0 }}">
                {{ answer.answer }}
            </label>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

{% if craft.app.request.param('answers') %}
    {% set correctAnswersByQuestion = [] %}
    {% for question in allQuestions %}
        {% set correctAnswer = question.answers|map(answer => answer.correct ? true : false) %}
        {% set correctAnswersByQuestion = correctAnswersByQuestion|push(correctAnswer) %}
    {% endfor %}

    <h2>Results:</h2>
    {% set totalCorrect = 0 %}
    {% for questionIndex, answerIndex in craft.app.request.param('answers') %}
        <p>Question {{ questionIndex+1 }} was {{ correctAnswersByQuestion[questionIndex][answerIndex] ? 'correct' : 'incorrect' }}</p>
        {% set totalCorrect = correctAnswersByQuestion[questionIndex][answerIndex] ? totalCorrect+1 : totalCorrect %}
    {% endfor %}

    <h2>Score:</h2>
    {{ totalCorrect/allQuestions|length * 100 }}%
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't really considered it, but that's an amazing start. I did say simple, but I would like the quiz to evolve in the future; for example, saving results to a User's profile, and possibly text input fields rather than just radio inputs.